# CORS post call not working in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am trying to implement cross-origin post call from angularjs application, then I get the following error.

Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

But, when I make a Ajax call it works properly.
How HTTP post call work in angularjs?

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: getAccessTokenUrl, 
            data: JSON.stringify(clintdata), 
            dataType: 'json', 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            success: function(resultData) { 
                console.log(resultData);    
            }, 
            error: function (request, status, error) { 
               console.log(status);  
            } 
        });
```

Angularjs HTTP call

```
$http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: getAccessTokenUrl,
          data: clientdata,
          headers: {
            'Authorization': undefined,
            'Auth-Token': undefined
          }
        }).then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
```

I have some default setting.  Authorization is for others REST

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8;' ;
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = 'X-Requested-With';
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = $('#Authorization').val();
```

Comment: did u enabled CORS on your backend? put more information about backend.

Comment: Yes, the above ajax call work properly.

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Phil. Now its work.

Comment: I don't understand. What changed between [it not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559146/cors-post-call-not-working-in-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment88130080_50559369) and now?

Comment: I am added the Authorization header dynamically. Previously Authorization header apply for all http call. because it is in run method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the following setting

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = 'X-Requested-With';
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = $('#Authorization').val();
```

Add Authorization header dynamically from Interceptor

```
request: function(config) {
if (angular.isUndefined(config.skipInterceptor) || !config.skipInterceptor) {
// add Authorization token
}
return config;
}
```

Http call like this

```
$http.post('your url', {
skipInterceptor: true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`Access-Control-*` headers are **response headers**. They come from the server in response to a request. You do not apply them to your request headers.

If your jQuery request works correctly without adding any additional headers, then your AngularJS request should work the same.

The equivalent jQuery request in AngularJS (including removing the *Authorization* and *Auth-Token* headers you've set via defaults) is

```js
$http.post(getAccessTokenUrl, clientdata, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: undefined,
    'Auth-Token': undefined
  }
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data)
})
```

or the long version

```js
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: getAccessTokenUrl,
  data: clientdata,
  headers: {
    Authorization: undefined,
    'Auth-Token': undefined
  }
}).then(...)
```

---

AngularJS by default...

- POSTS requests as `application/json` content-type
- Serializes the *data* property to JSON
- Expects a JSON response
- Resolves the `$http` promise with a `response` object with the response body parsed as JSON into the `data` property

Comment: I got the following error. "Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: I have some http default setting in run method. 
$http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8;' ;
   $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
   $http.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = 'X-Requested-With';
   $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = $('#Authorization').val();

Comment: @AlokeKantal I'll repeat, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is **not a request header**. Do not add it to `$http.defaults.headers.common` or anywhere else in your JS code

Comment: If I remove "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" form default setting it will work?

Comment: I wouldn't say with complete certainty that it will _work_ but you definitely should not have that in the request headers

Comment: After remove "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", I got the following error.          Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: @AlokeKantal why are you adding an `Authorization` header? Your jQuery request doesn't have one and the server endpoint doesn't allow it

Comment: I am adding this for other REST

Comment: @AlokeKantal then you'll need to exclude it from this request

Comment: I can't  get your last comment properly.

Comment: Even after applying your answer, I am getting same error "Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."